# SELECT com LIKE e LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Olá, estou tentando buscar registros baseado no nome da pedra e nas tags.

Tabelas:

```
** Tabela tag **
----------------
id       nome
----------------
1        Sem categoria
2        cs
3        weapon
4        balrog


** Tabela tag_relac **
----------------------
id_tag       id_pedra
----------------------
1        50
1        51
1        60
2        60
3        60
4        60    


** Tabela pedras **
-------------------
id         nome
-------------------
50        Teste
51        Teste 2
60        Balrog-1 Blue Explosion
```

Se eu definir o nome da pedra, funciona.

```
SELECT pedras.nome, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.nome ORDER BY tag.nome ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags FROM pedras LEFT JOIN tag_relac ON pedras.id = tag_relac.id_pedra LEFT JOIN tag ON tag_relac.id_tag = tag.id WHERE pedras.nome LIKE '%balrog%' OR tag.nome LIKE '%weapon%' GROUP BY pedras.id ORDER BY pedras.nome ASC
```

Agora, se eu definir o nome da tag, só retorna à que for relativa ao nome.

```
SELECT pedras.nome, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.nome ORDER BY tag.nome ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags FROM pedras LEFT JOIN tag_relac ON pedras.id = tag_relac.id_pedra LEFT JOIN tag ON tag_relac.id_tag = tag.id WHERE pedras.nome LIKE '%teste%' OR tag.nome LIKE '%weapon%' GROUP BY pedras.id ORDER BY pedras.nome ASC
```

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 0):

Se for o que eu to pensando é por causa do case sensitive... Você está buscando a pedra like "%teste%" mas no banco os nomes estão como "Teste".... a primeira busca retornou certo pois coincidentemente o nome da pedra que vc estava procurando estava na tag que bateu com o que vc digitou no like da tag

Comment: Consegui corrigir. Utilizei HAVING ao invés de WHERE.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415492/mysql-like-from-join-clause-and-group-concat-returns-only-one-row-from-joined-ta